# java - jsp update database row via form on submit

Tags: java, html, sql, jsp, sql-update

Hi im trying to update data from database using submit button , witch is located on a jsp page that shows data based on name and surname that you entered in login.jsp..

validationForDatabase.jsp shows data from the table pacijent,based on name and surname are entered in another jsp page. Fields name and surname are readonly so you can chage everything except those fileds, and when you make chages and press button Update it should redirect you to update.jsp. If the update is successful you sholud be redirected back to validationForDatabase.jsp but instead of doing that it shows me Badly entered data from else section.
Could you please guide me on how to fix this problem or maybe another way to do this.

Thanks in advance

validationForDatabase.jsp

```
    `
<%

    try{
    String name= request.getParameter("name");   
    String surname= request.getParameter("surname");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sth","root","");    
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select name,surname from pacijent where name=? and surname=?");
    pst.setString(1, name);
    pst.setString(2, surname);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();                        
    if(rs.next())
    { 
    out.println("Name of the patient :  "+name);
    out.println("<br/>Surname of the patient :  "+surname);
    HttpSession sesija = request.getSession();
    sesija.setAttribute("name", name);
    sesija.setAttribute("surname", surname);

    %>

    <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

    <%

    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sth";

    try {Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");} 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    %>

        <form action="Update.jsp" method="get">

        <%

        try{ 
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sth","root","");
        statement=connection.createStatement();
        String sql ="SELECT name,father,surname,birth,adress,phone,email,notes "+ "FROM pacijent where name='"+sesija.getAttribute("name")+"'and surname='"+surname+"';";
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while(resultSet.next()){

            %> 

        <p align="center"><%= sesija.getAttribute("name")%><%= sesija.getAttribute("surname")%></p>

        <p><label  class="uname">name</label><input name="name" readonly value="<%=sesija.getAttribute("name") %>"/></p>
        <p><label  class="uname">father</label><input name="father" value="<%=resultSet.getString("father") %>"/></p>
        <p><label  class="uname">surname</label><input name="surname" readonly value="<%=sesija.getAttribute("surname") %>"/></p>
        <p><label  class="uname">birth</label><input name="birth" value="<%=resultSet.getString("birth") %>"/></p>
        <p><label  class="uname">Adress</label><input name="adress" value="<%=resultSet.getString("adress ") %>"/></p>
        <p><label  class="uname">phone</label><input name="phone" value="<%=resultSet.getString("phone") %>"/></p>
        <p><label  class="uname" > E-mail</label><input name="email" value="<%=resultSet.getString("email") %>"/></p>
        <p><label for="usernamesignup" class="uname">info</label>
        <textarea name="notes" id="a" class="a" rows="4" cols="60" 
        textareaObject.value="text" ><%= resultSet.getString("notes") %></textarea></p>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update" />

                                             </form>

            <% 
            }
            connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sesija.invalidate();
            %>


            <%  
                }
                else{ 
            %>
                       <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><h1 align="center">Badly entered data</h1> 
                    <%}
               }
               catch(Exception e){       
                   out.println("Error "+e);       
               }      
            %>`
```

Update.jsp works in redirecting back but it wont update data.

Update.jsp
`
    <%

```
            String name=request.getParameter("name");
            String father=request.getParameter("father");
            String surname=request.getParameter("surname");
            String birth=request.getParameter("birth");
            String adress =request.getParameter("adress ");
            String phone=request.getParameter("phone");
            String email=request.getParameter("email");
            String notes=request.getParameter("notes");





            try {
                Connection conn = null;
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sth", "root", "");
                Statement st1 = null;
                st1 = conn.createStatement();
                HttpSession sesija = request.getSession();
                sesija.setAttribute("name", name);
                System.out.println(sesija.getAttribute(name));
                st1.executeUpdate("UPDATE pacijent SET name= '"+name+"',father= '"+father+"',"
                        + "surname= '"+surname+"',birth= '"+birth+"',adress = '"+adress +"',"
                        + "phone= '"+phone+"',email = '"+email+"',notes = '"+notes+"'"
                        + "WHERE name="+sesija.getAttribute(name));
                response.sendRedirect("validationForDatabase.jsp");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println("Error : " + e);
            }
        %>`
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Avoid using scriptlet in your code as much as you can

Comment: @Kedar1442 its a lot easier for me personally to have everything on one page, but ill try doing that.

Comment: There is a lot of "whys" that scriplets is bad [check this](http://www.theserverside.com/feature/Top-5-reasons-that-JSP-scriptlets-suck)